# A que se debe el error de tipo NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un java aplication en tres capas y a la hora de correr mi aplicación donde mostraría una pantalla principal me salta el siguiente error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/Principal$1
    at main.Principal.main(Principal.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.Principal$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Este es mi Principal.java desde donde se corre mi aplicación:

```
package main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import negocio.PersonaNegocio;
import negocioImpl.PersonaNegocioImpl;
import presentacion.controlador.Controlador;
import presentacion.vista.VentanaPrincipal;

public class Principal {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    VentanaPrincipal frame = new VentanaPrincipal();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    PersonaNegocio negocio = new PersonaNegocioImpl();
    //Controlador controlador = new Controlador(vista, negocio);
    //controlador.;
}
```

Y este es el archivo de la ventana que estoy mostrando:

```
package presentacion.vista;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class VentanaPrincipal extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public VentanaPrincipal() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        JMenu mnMenu = new JMenu("Persona");
        menuBar.add(mnMenu);
        
        JMenuItem mntmAgregar = new JMenuItem("Agregar");
        mnMenu.add(mntmAgregar);
        
        JMenuItem mntmModificar = new JMenuItem("Modificar");
        mnMenu.add(mntmModificar);
        
        JMenuItem mntmEliminar = new JMenuItem("Eliminar");
        mnMenu.add(mntmEliminar);
        
        JMenuItem mntmListar = new JMenuItem("Listar");
        mnMenu.add(mntmListar);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
    }
}
```

No estoy entendiendo el motivo del error. Estuve buscando en distintos sitios pero no logro entenderlo ni tampoco que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Tal vez podría servirte [esta publicación](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-solucionar-el-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-en-java.aspx). ;)

Answer (score 2):

El error `NoClassDefFound` lo que te indica es que:

- Estás programando en una clase `Miclase` donde importas algún paquete o clase externa XYZ y usas un método `metodo()` de esa clase externa.
- Durante el tiempo de compilación, tenías disponible en el classpath la clase `XYZ.class` (sola o dentro de alguna librería JAR). Tu clase `Miclase.java` se compila como `Miclase.class`
- Durante el tiempo de despliegue, esa clase XYZ no esta disponible, por lo que la instancia de la máquina virtual de Java no puede ejecutar el método que le estás pidiendo usar en el código.

Te dice *ajá, el class que estoy usando de tu clase es válido pero no tengo ni idea de qué hacer con el llamado a `XYZ.metodo()`*.

Debes ajustar el classpath que usas al correr tu aplicación, incluyendo los directorios en donde estén las clases compiladas que estés usando. No tiene ningúna relación con la configuración del proyecto mientras estás escribiendo el código.

- En un  proyecto dentro de un IDE, eso se configura normalmente al definir en las opciones de ejecución, de dónde jalar esas clases del classpath.
- Corriendo la clase usando la línea de comandos, suele usarse la opción `-cp` para definir el classpath

Así, la ejecución de la JVM (el classloader, específicamente) va a cargar inicialmente todas las clases que le estás diciendo que necesita preparar para correr tu código