# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError al usar un servicio en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, servicio

He hecho este servicio simple.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado las clases necesarias en el cliente con la opción automática de Eclipse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este cliente para usar el servicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo (El servicio está corriendo un servidor Tomcat en localhost), obtengo este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola, antes que nada, siempre pon código, logs y exceptions como texto, formateadas como código, es más fácil de entender así. En segundo lugar, un NoClassDefFoundError significa que estás tratando de usar algo que no tienes, estos dos enlaces podrían ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/a-que-se-debe-el-error -de-tipo-noclassdeffounderror y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efecto, el problema es que faltaban los paquetes que contenían esas clases, simplemente busqué dichos paquetes en mvnrepository y los fui añadiendo a mi .pom