# Problema al guardar en formato pdf el reporte

Tags: java, jasper-reports

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, les cuento que tengo un programa realizado en java el cual funciona muy bien al momento de imprimir, este es el código que utilizo para tal proceso:

```
private void cmdimprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        MyConnection cn = new MyConnection();
        Connection conn = cn.getConnection();
        JasperReport reporte = null;
        String path = "src/ventanas/cotizacion.jasper";
        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/ventanas/cotizacion.jasper"));
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, conn);
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        view.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frmpresupuesto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

y al momento de realizar con el botón dentro de los jasperreport (viewver), lo quiero guardar en formato pdf, anteriormente me funcionaba bien pero ahora no se porque, estos son lo errores que muestra y agregos las import que solicta y no graba:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor.save(JRPdfSaveContributor.java:110)
at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:421)
at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar$1.actionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:137)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 40 more
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal por lo cual favor de su ayuda y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` indica que compilas con unas cosas en el classpath, pero no están disponibles donde despliegas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [A que se debe el error de tipo NoClassDefFoundError?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/a-que-se-debe-el-error-de-tipo-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: que version de jasper resports estas usando?

Comment: @Alfabravo realice una actualización de las librerías y me da una advertencia ahora pero graba lo que quiero en el formato de pdf, anteriormente me daba los errores antes indicados

Comment: @RuslanLópez realice una actualización de las librerías y me da una advertencia ahora pero graba lo que quiero en el formato de pdf, anteriormente me daba los errores antes indicados

Comment: No estás respondiendo completo. Si actualizas, tienes que garantizar que esas versiones actualizadas estén también en el classpath de despliegue

Comment: y entones... que version de jasper resports estas usando? – 
Ruslan López
 hace 2 días

Comment: @Alfabravo te comento que la actualice y funciona muy bien al momento del despliegue y funciona muy bien en la red local graba en formato pdf y solo el mensaje de advertencia que solo se ve cuando uno lo realiza las pruebas en el servidor local

Comment: @RuslanLópez te informo que estaba utilizando la versión 6.13 y la cambie a la 6.18.1 y funciona y como dije me graba bien en formato pdf

Comment: @Hector te sugiero crear una respuesta a tu propia pregunta con esa informacion

Comment: @RuslanLópez la coloco mañana, ya que no me encuentro con mi equipo personal en estos momentos.

Answer (score 1):

amigos del foro, si les paso lo mismo que a mi con las librería del jasperreport de cambiarlas a la 6.13.1 hic lo siguiente:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer;
```

aunque en los tres últimos import le den advertencia, ocupenlo igual de todas maneras realiza el proceso de grabarlo en formato pdf, también hice la prueba en excel y funciona pero creo que se demora un poco, y en word a su vez, el código del boton imprimir funciona bien e imprime en cualquier impresora que se encuentre en la red local