# Lanzamiento de aplicación desktop en java con jdeveloper 12c

Tags: java, webservice, jdeveloper

Llevo un desarrollo en java en el cual hago consumo de un webservices (HTTP); no es abierto a internet sino que a través de una red interna, el cual usa certificados antes de realizar el consumo del webservices.

Fragmento de código.

Declaración de variables:

```java
String clientKeyStore = "cliente.jks";
String clientKeyStorePassword = "cliente";
String clientKeyAlias = "cliente";
String clientKeyPassword = "cliente";
String serverKeyStore = "cliente.cer";

X509Certificate serverCert = (X509Certificate) CertUtils.getCertificate(serverKeyStore);
```

Instancia del webservice:

```java
Lote loteServices = new Lote(); loteServices.registrar(xml)
```

Al ejecutarlo en el IDE de JDeveloper 12c me funciona sin ningún problema.

Luego de compilarlo, es decir sacar la aplicación .jar y probarlo con la consola en administrador, me muestra el siguiente error:

La ejecución se detiene en la siguiente linea revisando el código.

```java
X509Certificate serverCert = (X509Certificate)CertUtils.getCertificate(serverKeyStore);
```

me indica el error:

> Aug 30, 2022 4:19:08 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]
> selectAlternatives
> WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding"
> was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
> Aug 30, 2022 4:19:08 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]
> selectAlternatives
> WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EncryptedParts"
> was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
> Aug 30, 2022 4:19:08 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]
> selectAlternatives
> WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts"
> was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
> Aug 30, 2022 4:19:08 PM  [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]
> selectAlternatives
> WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Wss11" was
> evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
> Aug 30, 2022 4:19:08 PM  [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]
> selectAlternatives
> WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/wsee/security/util/CertUtils
> at gob.sv.bcr.lbtr.Form.Contingencia.Procesar(Contingencia.java:596)
> at gob.sv.bcr.lbtr.Form.Contingencia.btnProcesarActionPerformed(Contingencia.java:301)
> at gob.sv.bcr.lbtr.Form.Contingencia.access$000(Contingencia.java:81)
> at gob.sv.bcr.lbtr.Form.Contingencia$1.actionPerformed(Contingencia.java:177)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.wsee.security.util.CertUtils
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> ... 40 more

Ya he realizado lo siguiente:

- Al *Prueba.jar* lo he puesto en la carpeta junto a las librerías y certificados que se han utilizado.
- Se ha quemado y se le ha asignado a una variable la ruta en donde se encuentran los certificados.
- NO utiliza base de datos, sino que hace la consulta a un archivo en donde se almacena la información de configuración.
- Verifiqué las variables de entorno de JAVA por si eso era.
- Instalé los certificados en mi equipo local.
- He verificado que la carpeta en donde se encuentran los certificados tengan todos los permisos.

Y aún así no me funciona. ¿Qué debería hacer para hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy bien formulada! solo como nota, pasate por el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Buena pregunta! Debo pedir una aclaración: Qué versión de Weblogic y de Java usas?

Comment: Gracias Gbianchi, lo revisare para estar al tanto de como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Segun el meta inf de weblogic es
Bundle-SpecVersion: 1.0
Implementation-Version: 12.2.1.2.0
Source-Repository-Change-Id: 1827450
Specification-Title: weblogic.jar

y de JAVA 1.18

Comment: En los [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/wls/WLAPI/index.html?weblogic/wsee/security/unt/package-summary.html) de Weblogic no aparece esa clase `CertUtils`. Sin embargo, tu aplicación compila (pero no despliega). Entonces, una de dos: o tienes algo en el entorno de compilación de JDeveloper que no está cuando despliegas, o Weblogic tiene un jar en el classpath que sobreescribe algo que incluyes en tu proyecto (el classloader de Weblogic me hizo varias de traer ya incluidas versiones Oracle de librerías de terceros que no eran la que yo quería y las prefiere!)

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta, y hasta podria ser algo boba, pero como podria verificar los dos puntos que mencionas?, ojo soy nevo en estoy de la progrmacion con JAVA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás corriendo el JAR y sale [`NoClassDefFound`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/a-que-se-debe-el-error-de-tipo-noclassdeffounderror/536515#536515), significa que al empaquetar no estás incluyendo todo lo que usas para compilar (las librerías de terceros). Si el JAR sale sólo con las clases `com.vicente.prueba` (por ejemplo), cuando intentes instancias clases de otras librerías (weblogic.pepito, com.apache, etc.) no va a saber de dónde sacarlas (porque no están en el JAR y no tiene por qué saber dónde están, sin importar dónde ubiques el JAR).

En la pregunta que te enlazo se explica cómo resolver un error de este tipo.
En tu caso específico, tienes dos opciones:

- Revisa cómo construir un fatJar (o uberJar) que incluya todo lo que usas.
- Ejecuta tu jar (no nos dijiste nunca cómo lo ejecutas) indicando explícitamente el classpath.

```
java -cp /ruta/a/librerias1/*:ruta/a/librerias2/*:. -jar Prueba.jar
```

Y añades todos los directorios que ves que se reseñan en tu proyecto como que contienen librerías externas (el proyecto tiene su propio classpath!).

Ahí procuraría tener en cuenta las cosas que vienen con Weblogic, como

```
MW_HOME\wlserver_xx.y\server\lib\weblogic.jar
MW_HOME\wlserver_xx.y\server\lib\wls-api.jar
MW_HOME\wlserver_xx.y\server\lib\wseeclient.jar
```

No sé cuál de esos JAR te sirva porque, de nuevo, en la documentación no encontré esa clase que estás usando... pero en tu proyecto puedes identificarla.

Comment: Se me paso por alto, en la consola de comandos como administrador, me voy primero a la ruta en donde se encuentra el .jar

ejemplo 
c:\pruebas

luego escribo java -jar prueba.jar, presiono enter

y abre el aplicativo para verificar que todo este bien, al darle al boton de procesar es donde ocurre el problema.

tomar en cuenta que en dicho directorio estan todas las librerias y certificados

Comment: @VicenteCh como podrás imaginar, _al darle el botón de procesar_ es élfico antiguo porque no sé qué hace tu aplicación. Si revisas lo que te indico, debería funcionar sin importar en qué opción o pantalla del JAR está fallando

Comment: al final le hice el cambio de librerias, le modifique las rutas en donde las deberia encontrar, pero aparentemente es un problema del IDE Jdeveloper. de ante mano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Buenas @Alfabravo, justo logre agregar las librerías, agregando un archivo de manifiesto y agregándole el atributo de classpath , seguido de eso enlistar los nombres de las librerías a utilizar, por otro lado ahora me brinda error de clase no encontrada aun estando la librería en el proyecto y en el manifiesto.

Comment: @VicenteCh te sale clase no encontrada para la misma certutils? Es que las cosas oracle son un fastidio porque incluyen varias librerías precargadas y el classpath de despliegue incluye esas versiones que prefiere antes que los que tú le pongas... aclara en la pregunta, por favor

Comment: Hola buenas AlfaBravo, te comente que con lo de certUtil lo logre solventar cambiando el llamado **final X509Certificate serverCert = getCertObject(serverKeyStore)**, ya una vez solventado ese detalle sale lo mismo de clase no encontrada pero con el **weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider**, ya tiene las librerias pegadas en una direccion determinada, tambien estan declaradas en el manifiesto y como que le vale.