# ¿Por qué mi botón para generar un PDF por medio de iReport no me funciona?

Tags: java, java-swing, ireport

Ayuda en mi programa tengo un iReport con esta query:

```
SELECT idRegistroCarnet,nombre_responsable,fecha,periodo,observaciones,idEquipo,nombreFisico,nombreDominio,StatusNom,nombreMarca,nombreModelo,descripcion,tipo,numInventario,numSerie,ram,hardDisk,procesador,antiguedad,velocidadConexion,nombreSala,tipoConexion,Usuario,nombreSo,versionSo,puetoUsbFrente,puetoUsbPosterior,terjetaRed,tarjetaVideo,monitor,teclado,mouse FROM repswequip INNER JOIN registrocarnet USING (idRegistroCarnet) INNER JOIN semestre USING (idSemestre) INNER JOIN equipo USING (idEquipo) INNER JOIN status USING (idStatus) INNER JOIN software USING (idSoftware)INNER JOIN marca USING (idMarca) INNER JOIN modelo USING (idModelo) INNER JOIN tipoadquisicion USING (idTipoAdquisicion) INNER JOIN tipoequipo USING (idTipoEquipo) INNER JOIN sala USING (idSala) INNER JOIN conexion USING (idConexion) INNER JOIN tipousuariointernet USING (idTipoUsuarioEquip) INNER JOIN so USING(idSo)where idRegistroCarnet = $P{idRegistroCarnett}
```

Por lo tanto, el único dato que mando es el de `id` del registro, pero a la hora de darle al botón con el que que quiero que se mande el `id` y con ese `id` se llene el formulario pero no me sale nada:

```
    try {
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(ResgistroCarnet.class.getResource("/src/Reporte/Reporte_Prueba.jasper"));
        Map parametro = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        parametro.put("idRegistroCarnett", txtIDrc.getText());
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametro, new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jprint);
        jv.show();
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ResgistroCarnet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Me sale este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:141)
at Lab_Computonew.ResgistroCarnet.btnGenerarPdfActionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1913)
at Lab_Computonew.ResgistroCarnet.access$3000(ResgistroCarnet.java:47)
at Lab_Computonew.ResgistroCarnet$31.actionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1152)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

He intentado cambiando de nombre, la dirección del archivo pero me sigue pasando lo mismo.

aquí esta donde tengo los archivos(la clase desde donde llamo a reporte esta en lab_computonewin):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(cambie lo que se ve de reporte a lab_computonewin)

listo ya logre que ya no me saliera el mismo error

```
private void btnGenerarPdfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  
    try {
        
        JasperReport archivo = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("Reporte_prueba.jasper"));

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("idRegistroCarnett", txtIDrc.getText());
     con = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection();
    JRDataSource data = new JREmptyDataSource();
    JasperPrint prin = JasperFillManager.fillReport(archivo,map,con);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(prin,"reporte.pdf");
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(prin);
    jv.setVisible(true);
    jv.setTitle("Reporte Registro Carnet");

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ResgistroCarnet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ResgistroCarnet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

pero ahora me sale el siguiente error que no se como solucionarlo

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/GroovyEvaluator
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClass(JRClassLoader.java:338)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassFromBytes(JRClassLoader.java:261)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:320)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.loadEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:240)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:420)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:432)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:77)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:87)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:142)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:78)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet.btnGenerarPdfActionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1923)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet.access$3000(ResgistroCarnet.java:50)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet$31.actionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1155)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 55 more
```

veo que algunos ponen las librerias aqui estan las que uso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

listo ya resolví el otro problema que salió pero ahora me salió otro error:

```
nov 11, 2022 12:29:23 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment findComponentBundles ADVERTENCIA: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:326)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet.btnGenerarPdfActionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1923)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet.access$3000(ResgistroCarnet.java:50)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet$31.actionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1155)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

bueno volví a solucionarlo al parecer por tener la librería javaflow me generaba un problema, pero como no me salio de nuevo otro problema y ahora es este:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unknown hyperlink target 0
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRHyperlinkHelper.getLinkTarget(JRHyperlinkHelper.java:269)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField.normalizeLinkTarget(JRBaseTextField.java:313)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField.readObject(JRBaseTextField.java:377)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:552)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:742)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:143)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet.btnGenerarPdfActionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1917)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet.access$3000(ResgistroCarnet.java:50)
at Lab_Computonewin.ResgistroCarnet$31.actionPerformed(ResgistroCarnet.java:1155)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Pues el loadObject está dando NullPointerException porque no lo encuentra. Esa ruta no es correcta. Prueba usando `/` (uno solo) en la ruta y revisa cuál es la ubicación relativa del .jasper respecto del directorio raíz donde ejecutas tu aplicación

Comment: ya le cambie pero me sigue apareciendo igual, mmm como veo la direccion?

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta tu estructura de archivos, principalmente donde se ubican el archivo .jasper, la clase `ResgistroCarnet` y la clase donde llamas al reporte.

Comment: Cuando tú compilas y despliegas tu aplicación, lo que está en src se publica en diferentes lugares. Los class van en una parte, los resources (los estáticos) van en otra parte. Y normalmente uno no busca nada en src porque eso no está en tu app cuando la pones en el servidor web (en el tomcat o donde sea). Te correspnde mostrarnos la estructura de archivos de tu proyecto para poderte ayudar ;)

Comment: ya pude dar solucion al primero per me sigue saliendo error ahora en la linea  JasperPrint prin = JasperFillManager.fillReport(archivo,map,con);

Comment: Respuesta relevante al segundo error: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/536515/6798

Comment: Por favor: versión de iReport que estás usando y versión de la librería jasperreports que estás cargando en el proyecto? Ese error sale cuando compilas con una y despliegas con otra...

Comment: ya lo solucione el problema es que antes intentando ver que pasaba cambie el jasperreport 3.7.0 por un jasperreport 4.7.1, y regrese al jasper 3.7.0 lo cual me generaba un problema, lo que hice fue volver a poner el jasper 4.7.1 y se soluciono

Comment: Asegúrate de compilar y ejecutar con la misma versión de Jasper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error estaba asociado a la ruta de tu archivo .jasper. Cuando construyes y despliegas en un contenedor o servidor web, los recursos estáticos no quedan en ninguna carpeta src (que no existe). Por ello, es necesario ver dónde ubicas estos recursos en el war o en el artefacto que sea que construyes. Ahí podrás poner una ruta correcta :)

EL segundo error indica que en tiempo de compilación había librerías disponibles, pero en tiempo de despliegue ya no están. Más sobre eso en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/536515/6798).
En tu caso específico, sin embargo, posiblemente no sea necesario ponerse a añadir encarnaciones de groovy. A menos que hagas cosas muuuy puntuales, podrías buscar en la definición xml (en el jrxml) dentro de iReport y cambiar el `language="groovy"` por `language="java"`.

Comment: Gracias me funciono pero parece que hay error tras error :( ahora me salio este:   nov 11, 2022 12:19:39 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment findComponentBundles
ADVERTENCIA: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Oscar nope, tienes que editar la pregunta y añadir la nueva traza. NullPointerException puede ser en cualquier cosa :P

Comment: okas, listo ya lo modifique